# How to add a big curly brace to label the side of a table?

Tags: tables, brackets, braces

How can I use a big curly brace to group together lines of a table on the left side?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{$n=3$}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
 \hline
 Partition of $n$ & Conjugacy Class Representative\\
 \hline
 $1+1+1$ & $(1)$\\
 \hline
 $1+2$ & $(12)$\\
 \hline
 $3$ & $(123)$\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{$n=4$}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
 \hline
 Partition of $n$ & Conjugacy Class Representative\\
 \hline
 $1+1+1+1$ & $(1)$\\
 \hline
 $1+1+2$ & $(12)$\\
 \hline
 $2+2$ & $(12)(34)$\\
 \hline
 $1+3$ & $(123)$\\
 \hline
 $4$ & $(1234)$\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313992/197451  --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624505/197451

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array` instead of `tabular` environments and encase each `array` environment in a `\left\{ ... \right.` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
n=3 
\left\{ \begin{array}{ |c|c| } 
 \hline
 \text{Partition of $n$} & \text{Conjugacy Class Representative}\\
 \hline
 1+1+1 & (1)\\
 \hline
 1+2 & (12)\\
 \hline
 3 & (123)\\
 \hline
\end{array}\right.
\]

\[
n=4 
\left\{ \begin{array}{ |c|c| } 
 \hline
 \text{Partition of $n$} & \text{Conjugacy Class Representative}\\
 \hline
 1+1+1+1 & (1)\\
 \hline
 1+1+2 & (12)\\
 \hline
 2+2 & (12)(34)\\
 \hline
 1+3 & (123)\\
 \hline
 4 & (1234)\\
 \hline
\end{array} \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple and nice suggestion...